# how to handle events in MVC 4 (ASPX)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new in MVC ,created application in VS12 MVC4 with ASPX selection.I have design master page. created one controller and then view from controller->add view
with nested created master page. 
My view code is like below(show only required code)

```
<asp:Table runat ="server"  HorizontalAlign ="Center" >
        <asp:TableRow >
            <asp:TableCell >                    
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnlogin" runat="server" Text="Login"></dx:ASPxButton>
            </asp:TableCell>
             <asp:TableCell >
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"></dx:ASPxButton>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
```

how to redirect to another page after login successfully?

Comment: MVC uses controllers, your controller handles the action (loging in in this example) and then redirects the user to a different View. Why are you using aspx at all if you are creating a new web application? Use razor and the standard MVC layout (controller, model, view). My advice? Stop what you are doing and pick up a book or follow an online tutorial.

Comment: @Igor- ok now I started to use Razor, now tell me how to handle login event with default ID,password

Comment: What you are asking is MVC 101, how to create an action/post. Its the equivalent of going on a forum for car lovers and asking them to explain what an engine is. Again, go do some reading / follow along tutorials. To get you started:  [Learn About ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview), [ASP.NET MVC Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_app.asp), [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started), [MVC recommended tutorials and articles](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/mvc-learning-sequence).

Answer (score 1):

d0812!

Actually, in your home controller, in method Index (which should call firstly for client by default) something like this will be:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

It means the following for your application: If client calls http(s)://yourapp/ or http(s)://yourapp/home, this method will invokes.
ActionResult is a server response in general.

Next, client will recieve file with name Index from folder /(root)/Views/Home/.

But you can also do this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("myViewName");
    }
}
```

and then your client will come to the file with a name myViewName in the same folder.

Thus you can check for identity of your client:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return View("myViewName");
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Next, you cant implement POST method for client authorization with the attribute

```
    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
             //TODO: implement
             //note: you can redirect the user here 
             //as described above
        }
```

where LoginModel is just serializable class:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

or start using [something like owin2](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server)

I hope, it will help you.